# buf generate: exclude paths with using a template yaml

Tags: buf

I am using `buf` cli with version `1.5.0` to generate proto files for both `Go` and `C#`

File structure of my protobuf definitions is as follows:

```
service1
-> proto
--> def
----> go_only_protos
-------> hello.proto
service2
-> proto
--> def
----> go_only_protos
-------> echo.proto
```

When I want to generate protos for `C#` with the following template:

```yaml
version: v1
plugins:
  - name: csharp
    out: ./.gen/csharp
    opt: base_namespace=Hello.Io.Proto
```

How can I pass these paths to exclude? I do not want to pass these paths to cli command such as:

`buf generate --exclude-path="service1/proto/def/go_only_protos" --template=...`

Is it possible to add a config to this template or another file, like `buf.yaml`?